# Add date + time variable to results files

Tags: python, datetime

I am starting out in Python.

I am doin a quality control analysis of data and I am looking for a function that adds the date and time to the figures/tables/data that comes out of the jupyter notebook.

I found the `datetime` Python package and I wanted to ask how to use it to add a date variable to these outputs.

As an example, this is the line to store an adata object in a file:

`adata.write(data_dir + 'data_filtered.h5ad')`

Any ideas on how I could add a date variable to it so that if I repeat it tomorrow I can distinguish the different analysis?

As I mentioned, I am starting out so I would appreciate your help a lot.

Edit

I would like to add the date to the file name and in the case of tables and figures add in them as well.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to add a date to the figure or the data in the file or the file name itself?

Comment: `datetime.date.today().isoformat()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the date(time) in the name of the file, replace :

```py
adata.write(data_dir + 'data_filtered.h5ad')
```

by

```py
import datetime as dt
current_date = dt.date.today()
current_date_str = current_date.isoformat()

filename = data_dir + 'data_filtered_' + current_date_str + '.h5ad'
adata.write(filename)
```